# How do I return if HashMap has even as value

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

```
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
//assume hm is populated

if(hm.containValue(***){ ... }
// *** = contains even number
```

I tried to do something like `(x -> x % 2 == 0)` but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming we have a predicate:

```
Predicate<Integer> isEvenNumber = x -> x % 2 == 0;
```

---

To check if a `map` has an even number among its values:

```
boolean containsEvenNumber = map.values().stream().anyMatch(isEvenNumber);
```

To count all even numbers:

```
long countEvenNumbers = map.values().stream().filter(isEvenNumber).count();
```

To get all even numbers

- with a list:

  ```
  List<Integer> evenNumbers = map.values().stream().filter(isEvenNumber).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- with an array:

  ```
  int[] evenNumbers = map.values().stream().filter(isEvenNumber).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
  ```

Comment: and if i want to return if I have more then one even number?

Comment: "and if i want to return if I have more then one even number? "
=> `hm.values().stream().filter(x->x%2==0).count() > 1` I think so J

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Ah, I just answer the PO's question :D

Answer (score 2):

Following code gives you the Boolean true if there is any even number found in the map's values otherwise false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Initialize Map         
    Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String , Integer>(){{
        put("A", 1);
        put("B", 3);
        put("C", 4);
        put("D", 7);
    }};

    boolean foundEven = hm.values()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0);

    System.out.println(foundEven);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should manually loop the values to check each of them:

```
for (int i : hm.values()) {
    if( i % 2 == 0) {
        //do what you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, OK I got it. I just want to show PO how to get what he want. ANW, thank you.